# Create new Object Class in OpenDJ (LDAP) from JAVA

Tags: java, ldap

I have to create a custom Object Class in LDAP server from java JNDI. The object class should have 3 fields with values: Name, OID, Description. So far
I have managed to only define the environment.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();

    properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapUrl);
    properties.put(Context.REFERRAL, "ignore");
    properties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, dirManagerUser);
    properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

    DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(properties);

    //NEW CUSTOM OBJECT CREATION SHOULD GO HERE

    ctx.close();
```

Comment: Why from Java? You can do it administratively. You only have to do it once. No point writing code when you don't need to.

Comment: Its not up to me to decide. It's a given task.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
BasicAttribute attribute = new BasicAttribute("objectClasses");
        attribute.add(parameters);
        attributes.put(attribute);
        context.modifyAttributes("cn=schema",DirContext.ADD_ATTRIBUTE, attributes);
        context.close();
```